# interrogative "to be" sentence for 2nd person plural with "Where"

Tags: past-tense, questions

According to structure of the interrogative sentence for "to be", when I want to ask about a location of a [2nd person](https://www.grammarly.com/blog/first-second-and-third-person/) then I have to use "**were**" continuously after "**where**"

For example:

> **Where were** you yesterday.

Now my question if it's practical for use, or consider as a case of "just in the book" and practically I should avoid it and people actually use other structures like "**Where have you been yesterday**" in order to avoid this confusing words (where were) together. Or it is very common in use (it's something that I didn't notice...).

Comment: I am confused. What is your question? "Where were you yesterday?" is the only way to ask that question. [I think you mean "right after **where**" and not continuously.

Comment: I added some information in the end of the post. Kindly look at this and let me know if my question is already more clear (clearer).

Comment: There is nothing confusing about "where were you" at all. In fact, where, when, how, why are all followed by was/were in questions.

Comment: Here's a hint that might help you: when we say "yesterday", we're obviously talking about the past.  But *have* is actually in the present tense!  That's why "where have you been yesterday?" doesn't work.

Comment: @stangdon Yes, but it's rather arcane for ELLing.

Comment: @stangdon, I'm sorry but I don't agree. I remember that in my school book one of the rules for using present perfect tense was for what you noted, but another usage was for people who don't want / care to mention the time in the past. I will try to find a respected references for that, but in the meantime I found this thing: **"The present perfect tense refers to an action or state that either occurred at an indefinite time in the past"** https://www.grammarly.com/blog/present-perfect-tense/

Comment: See here p.329: "This tense sometimes represents an action as having been completed at some indefinite time in the past. e.g. *I have played more that 1,000 rounds of golf.*. **but sometimes, too, the present perfect indicates that an action continues to the present**" (The Oxford Dictionary of American Usage and Style) I saw it in the past in another literature of Oxford.

Comment: @stangdon See what I mean?

Comment: @subtle_sibling : yes, but *yesterday* isn't an "indefinite time in the past", it's a specific one.

Comment: Indeed, I agree now and I did before. My note was about what you said in the end of your things "but have is actually in the present tense". But anyway now I think that I got you.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ymgexYXqadY how to pronounce "where" "were" and "war"

Comment: Thank you. This one is even cooler: **"If I were where you were, I would wear warfare ware there"**  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MLqE5U-2eWM

Comment: "Where were you" is not at all confusing for native speakers as it's an expected combination. Other homonyms can be much worse.  Anyway the words don't really sound the same.

Comment: @subtle_sibling - *have* is in the present tense, because the past would be **had**, is what I mean - it's just like "I have a dog" vs. "I had a dog."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Question forms: where, when, how, why + finished actions or time periods.

- Where **were you** yesterday?
- When **were you** here last?
- Why **were you** here?
- How **were you** the right person for the job?

Where **were you** yesterday? [yesterday is past]

Where **have you been** all morning? [**It is still morning**]

**Without going into every single usage of the  present perfect**, in general, if an action or time period is finished, we use simple past.

Generally, with time limiters like yesterday, two days ago, last month, last week, we use simple past. **The simple past for the verb to be is "was" or "were".**

Comment: So "where were you yesterday" is completely correct and common in use. I don't have to hesitate to use it. Isn't it? (for me both "where" and "were" sound the same and it make me feel not convenient to say continuously two words that sound the same. But if this considered absolutely correct I'll use it:)

Comment: It is completely correct, yes. You can find exercises on uTube. We say" one right after the other". Not continuously. :)

Answer (score 2):

I'm  not sure I completely understand the question.  But I'll try.

Short answer: yes.  You need the were.

- Where were you yesterday?   A question. I looked and looked but couldn't find you.  Where on earth were you yesterday? Note even the preposition "on" doesn't get you out of using were.
- Where you were yesterday.   A reference to an already known location.  Let's go back to that place you were at yesterday.

Probably an important addition is your parenthetical comment (it's something that I didn't noticed...).  While perhaps not textbook wrong that phraseology would never be used in practice.  Choices are

- it's something I hadn't noticed (or "had not" of course)
- it's something I didn't notice.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. "didn't notice" was a typo, but the rest were not.